# How to Fix Blank Email Error when User Signs up with Facebook (through Omniauth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, authentication, omniauth

I allow Facebook authentication on my Rails website and use Omniauth for it. I recently received the following error in production:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email can't be blank,
>   Email is invalid

Normally Facebook signup works fine, so what would cause this specific error? Below is my code for creating a User with Omniauth.

```
def self.create_from_omniauth(auth)
   where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth[:info][:email]
      user.password = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(n=10)
      user.save!
   end
end
```

Comment: and you verified that auth[:info][:email] exists and is valid?  or should it be `auth.info.email` ?

Comment: @Doon, i think its equivalent. Facebook signup usually works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, there has been a lot of discussion about this [issue in the omniauth-facebook repo](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/61).

I think the user [TeamRainless is the one who got closest to the answer:](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/61#issuecomment-21229945)

> Some users have supplied a phone number which facebook uses as it's main authentication method instead of the email address. I believe the phone number is then encrypted and that becomes what the email address would normally be.

The only solution to this problem is to redirect the user to a form where the registration process will be completed. Check out the [Railscasts OmniAuth Part 2 episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2) on how to do this.